# How to remove the “Powered by Cognito Forms” in email notification

Tags: cognito-forms

In the footer of the email notifications, there is this line “*Powered by Cognito Forms. Cognito Forms.*”

Is it possible to get rid of this?

Comment: @pnuts Not exactly the same thing, as here the OP is referring to the email notifications, while in the previous question the OP was referring to the web form. In my opinion at least.

Answer (score 1):

May 2016: Cognito Forms branding is completely removed from forms and emails on all of our paid plans.  This was partially accomplished when we launched paid plans last year, and with our May release of our referral program, we have completed the process.

---

Feb 2015: We are currently working on paid plans and are considering this as an option for these plans.  For the safety of our service, we must include this on our free plan, as we would otherwise be the target of overwhelming abuse by not nice people.

And in case you are wondering, all of the great features of Cognito Forms will remain free when we add paid plans in a couple of months.  We will also continue to add tons of free features in the future.  However, we have some upcoming features for organizations, like hiding this notice, that will require a paid plan.

Comment: since we have already used your form builder and we have to go live ASAP and in doing so only hurdle is the powered by thing so can you provide a temp solution to remove it till you come up with the paid plan. we are ready to pay you onetime fees for removing this. Please revert back to us ASAP.

Comment: Our April release is live.  Starting with our $10 Pro plan, we automatically remove the "Powered by Cognito Forms" message from confirmation emails.